# How can I stop video when user is scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, tableview

I have a tableView which gets data from the database. Some of the cells in my TableView contain videos in them and when we come across a video it displays properly.

My issue is that if someone keeps scrolling then that video still keeps playing. I would like to change that and if the user watches part of a video then keeps scrolling then I would like to end the video right there. I think I'm close to solving that issue but not quite there yet.

This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Home", for: indexPath) as! Home
    let filename = streamsModel.video_image[indexPath.row] as NSString
    if filename.pathExtension == "mov" {
        let movieURL = URL(string: streamsModel.video_image[indexPath.row])

        cell.videoCapHeight.constant = CGFloat(Float(cell.pic_height!))
        cell.playerView = AVPlayer(url: movieURL!)
        cell.MyAVPlayer.player = cell.playerView
        cell.MyAVPlayer.showsPlaybackControls = false
        cell.MyAVPlayer.view.frame = cell.videoView.bounds
        cell.videoView.addSubview(cell.MyAVPlayer.view)
        controller.addChildViewController(cell.MyAVPlayer)
        cell.playerView?.isMuted = false
        cell.MyAVPlayer.player?.play()

    }
    return cell
}
```

That code above simply checks to see if the `streamsModel.video_image` has a .mov extension (JSON). If it does, then it gets the movie/video and displays it in a AVPlayer.

As you can see from the code, the `Play()` method is used so videos start playing automatically. The problem is that if a video is, for instance, 1 minute long and you watch 20 seconds of it and you scroll down, you still hear that video playing and I would like to stop the video as soon as the user scrolls away.

This is my scrollView code now I just need to stop the videos here on scroll or maybe in UITableViewCell:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y + 0) {
        print("scrolling up")
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        print("scrolling down")
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: So if two cells next to each other both have video and display at the same time, they will both play automatically? - might want to consider changing how that works at some point.

Comment: Not quite only 1 video starts at a time . The cells are big enough so you can only be on 1 cell at a time since they contain other content .

Comment: Thats fair enough for now, but what if they get shown on a larger device? - I'd want to consider that before a user gets bombarded with more noise than they bargained for.

Comment: Yeah you have a point, I will look into that now as that will definitely become a problem .

Comment: There are `willDisplayCell` and `didEndDisplayingCell` delegate methods that tell you when a cell is coming on/off screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan's suggestion of using the table view's delegate method would work well for you here meaning you can pause the video as the cell moves off screen.

**Something like this should work:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Dequeue the cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Home", for: indexPath) as! Home
    // Check the player object is set (unwrap it)
    if let player = cell.MyAVPlayer.player {
        // Check if the player is playing
        if player.rate != 0 {
            // Pause the player
            player.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

I would suggest that automatically pausing and playing again could be a little bit laggy depending on if there is buffering going on etc... so you may want to consider allowing the user to play the videos on a tap.